# aurelia application startup errors in both ie and chrome

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to copy the code of the contact app from the aurelia repo in a asp.net 5 application using typescript 1.5 beta.
I copied all the files, the tsconfig configuration seems ok, but when I run the application, after the initial screen, I obtain errors in oth **ie11** and **chrome 42**.

In Ie 11 I receive the error message:

> JavaScript runtime error: Cannot define property 'Symbol(id)_i.jtkqmdozsa6': object is not extensible

calling configureAurelia  in the handleApp function

In Chrome I obtain

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__decorate' of undefined

in the same place.
How can I find the problem?

Comment: Getting this too, in IE 11 but not in Firefox. I'm not using TypeScript though. I'm using ES6, Babel and jspm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the TS 1.5 compiler's --emitDecoratorMetadata flag to true.

Comment: I think I set correctly in the tsconfig.json file

`    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "wwwroot/dist"
    }`

Comment: you are in visual studio, right?  i'll be porting some samples today and tomorrow, i'll take a look and get back to you with my experiences :)